# Map ListBoxFor items to ICollection with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

How do I configure AutoMapper to map an integer array (populated from a multi-select MVC ListBoxFor element) to an ICollection property of my domain object? Basically I want to set the domain object's PatientTypes and ProviderTypes properties to whatever the user selected in the list box and then save the object back to the database.

**Domain object**

```
public class Document
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PatientType> PatientTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProviderType> ProviderTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class DocumentEditModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Patient Type")]
    public int[] SelectedPatientTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList PatientTypeList { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Provider Type")]
    public int[] SelectedProviderTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList ProviderTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int pid)
{
    var model = Mapper.Map<DocumentEditModel>(_documentRepository.Find(pid));
    model.ProviderTypeList = new SelectList(_providerTypeRepository.All.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "ID", "Value");
    model.PatientTypeList = new SelectList(_patientTypeRepository.All.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "ID", "Value");

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(DocumentEditModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var document = Mapper.Map(model, _documentRepository.Find(model.ID));
        document.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

        _documentRepository.InsertOrUpdate(document);
        _documentRepository.Save();

        return null;
    }

    model.ProviderTypeList = new SelectList(_providerTypeRepository.All.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "ID", "Value");
    model.PatientTypeList = new SelectList(_patientTypeRepository.All.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "ID", "Value");

    return View(model);
}
```

**AutoMapper Config**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Document, DocumentEditModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DocumentEditModel, Document>();
```

Comment: Is `Document - PatientTypes/ProviderTypes ` many to many?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just didn't illustrate that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the associations are many to many you only have to create junction records in the database. A convenient way to do this is clear the collection and add items to it. Let's take `Document.PatientTypes` as an example:

```
var document = Mapper.Map(model, _documentRepository.Find(model.ID));
document.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

// Set the new associatins with PatientTypes
document.PatientTypes.Clear();
foreach(var pt in model.PatientTypeList.Select(id => new PatientType{Id = id}))
{
    document.PatientTypes.Add(pt);
}

_documentRepository.InsertOrUpdate(document);
_documentRepository.Save();
```

(I had to make some assumption wrt property names)

What happens here is that the existing records in the `DocumentPatientTypes` junction table are replaced by a new set of records. This is done by using so called [*stub entities*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx), the `new PatientType`s. You don't have to fetch the real ones from the database first, since the only thing EF needs is the Id value to create a new junction record.

As you see, I silently took Automapper out of the equation. It would be overkill to map a list of integers to `PatientType`. The `Select` is easy enough, and with a bit of experience one immediately recognized the stub entity pattern, which would otherwise be concealed by a `Mapper.Map` statement.

Comment: This is getting me 90% of the way there. I have to attach "pt" to the DbContext before calling .Add(), which works great the first time. However, when editing it a second time, I get the error about not being able to attach an entity that is already attached.

Comment: Looks like the lifespan of your context (or `documentRepository`) is too long. Create a new one for each request.

Comment: Unfortunately the company I'm working for has a convoluted process for their context management that they're requiring I use. Having said that, I was able to find a way around it using your solution as a basis.

Comment: OK, well done. Try to make a strong case for healthy context lifetime management though, it's pivotal for working with EF. And more fun!